# Elasticsearch index operation fails on complex object

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, lucene

I am indexing a data stream to Elasticsearch and I cannot figure out how to normalize incoming data to make it index without error. I have a mapping type "getdatavalues" which is a meta-data query. This meta-data query can return very different looking responses but I'm not seeing the difference. The error I get:

```
{"index":{"_index":"ens_event-2016.03.11","_type":"getdatavalues","_id":"865800029798177_2016_03_11_03_18_12_100037","status":400,"error":"MapperParsingException[object mapping for [getdatavalues] tried to parse field [output] as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?]"}}
```

when performing:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://192.168.99.100:80/es/ens_event-2016.03.11/getdatavalues/865800029798177_2016_03_11_03_18_12_100037' -d '{
  "type": "getDataValues",
  "input": {
    "deviceID": {
      "IMEI": "865800029798177",
      "serial-number": "64180258"
    },
    "handle": 644,
    "exprCode": "200000010300140000080001005f00a700000000000000",
    "noRollHandle": "478669308-578452",
    "transactionID": 290
  },
  "timestamp": "2016-03-11T03:18:12.000Z",
  "handle": 644,
  "output": {
    "noRollPubSessHandle": "478669308-578740",
    "publishSessHandle": 1195,
    "status": true,
    "matchFilter": {
      "prefix": "publicExpr.operatorDefined.commercialIdentifier.FoodSvcs.Restaurant.\"A&C Kabul Curry\".\"Rooster Street\"",
      "argValues": {
        "event": "InternationalEvent",
        "hasEvent": "anyEvent"
      }
    },
    "transactionID": 290,
    "validFor": 50
  }
}'
```

Here's what Elasticsearch has for the mapping:

```
  "getdatavalues" : {
    "dynamic_templates" : [ {
      "strings" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "index" : "not_analyzed",
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "match_mapping_type" : "string"
      }
    } ],
    "properties" : {
      "handle" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "input" : {
        "properties" : {
          "deviceID" : {
            "properties" : {
              "IMEI" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
              "serial-number" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "exprCode" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "handle" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "noRollHandle" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "serviceVersion" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "transactionID" : {
            "type" : "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "output" : {
        "properties" : {
          "matchFilter" : {
            "properties" : {
              "argValues" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "Interests" : {
                    "type" : "object"
                  },
                  "MerchantId" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "Queue" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "Vibe" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "event" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "event" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                      },
                      "hasEvent" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "hasEvent" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "interests" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              },
              "prefix" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
              "transactionID" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "validFor" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "noRollPubSessHandle" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "publishSessHandle" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "status" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "transactionID" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "validFor" : {
            "type" : "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "timestamp" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "type" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Can you send the request to elasticsearch immediately without the proxy in between? Tried the curl request to my local elastic 2.2.1 as well as 1.7.1 instance and it just seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the argValues object doesn't quite agree with your mapping:

```
        "argValues": {
            "event": "InternationalEvent",
            "hasEvent": "anyEvent"
        }
```

Either this:

```
        "argValues": {
            "event": {
                "event": "InternationalEvent"
            },
            "hasEvent": "anyEvent"
        }
```

Or this:

```
        "argValues": {
            "event": {
                "event": "InternationalEvent"
                "hasEvent": "anyEvent"
            },
        }
```

Would both seem to be valid.